# Cython: ctypedef char array throws obscure error

Tags: arrays, cython

Why does this work:

```
In [17]: %%cython -f
    ...: from libc.string cimport memcpy
    ...:
    ...: DEF KLEN = 5
    ...: DEF TRP_KLEN = KLEN * 3
    ...:
    ...: cdef:
    ...:     unsigned char k[KLEN]
    ...:     unsigned char kk[TRP_KLEN]
    ...: kk = bytearray(b'12345abcde!@#$%')
    ...: memcpy(&k, &kk[5], KLEN)
    ...: print(k)
b'abcde'
```

While this:

```
In [16]: %%cython -f
    ...: from libc.string cimport memcpy
    ...: 
    ...: DEF KLEN = 5
    ...: DEF TRP_KLEN = KLEN * 3
    ...: ctypedef unsigned char SingleKey[KLEN]
    ...: ctypedef unsigned char TripleKey[TRP_KLEN]
    ...: 
    ...: cdef:
    ...:     SingleKey k
    ...:     TripleKey kk
    ...: kk = bytearray(b'12345abcde!@#$%')
    ...: memcpy(&k, &kk[5], KLEN)
    ...: print(k)
```

throws an obscure error, which doesn't directly mention my code:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-a4bb608248b0> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic('cython', '-f', "from libc.string cimport memcpy\n\nDEF KLEN = 5\nDEF TRP_KLEN = KLEN * 3\nctypedef unsigned char SingleKey[KLEN]\nctypedef unsigned char DoubleKey[TRP_KLEN]\n\ncdef:\n    SingleKey k[KLEN]\n    DoubleKey kk[TRP_KLEN]\nkk = bytearray(b'12345abcde!@#$%')\nmemcpy(&k, &kk[5], KLEN)\nprint(k)")

/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in run_cell_magic(self, magic_name, line, cell)
   2165             magic_arg_s = self.var_expand(line, stack_depth)
   2166             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2167                 result = fn(magic_arg_s, cell)
   2168             return result
   2169

<decorator-gen-118> in cython(self, line, cell)

/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.py in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    185     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    186     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 187         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    188
    189         if callable(arg):

~/code/lsup/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Cython/Build/IpythonMagic.py in cython(self, line, cell)
    318         extension = None
    319         if need_cythonize:
--> 320             extensions = self._cythonize(module_name, code, lib_dir, args, quiet=args.quiet)
    321             assert len(extensions) == 1
    322             extension = extensions[0]

~/code/lsup/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Cython/Build/IpythonMagic.py in _cythonize(self, module_name, code, lib_dir, args, quiet)
    426             elif sys.version_info[0] >= 3:
    427                 opts['language_level'] = 3
--> 428             return cythonize([extension], **opts)
    429         except CompileError:
    430             return None

~/code/lsup/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py in cythonize(module_list, exclude, nthreads, aliases, quiet, force, language, exclude_failures, **options)
   1024     if not nthreads:
   1025         for args in to_compile:
-> 1026             cythonize_one(*args)
   1027
   1028     if exclude_failures:

~/code/lsup/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py in cythonize_one(pyx_file, c_file, fingerprint, quiet, options, raise_on_failure, embedded_metadata, full_module_name, progress)
   1127     any_failures = 0
   1128     try:
-> 1129         result = compile_single(pyx_file, options, full_module_name=full_module_name)
   1130         if result.num_errors > 0:
   1131             any_failures = 1

~/code/lsup/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py in compile_single(source, options, full_module_name)
    647     recursion.
    648     """
--> 649     return run_pipeline(source, options, full_module_name)
    650
    651

~/code/lsup/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py in run_pipeline(source, options, full_module_name, context)
    497
    498     context.setup_errors(options, result)
--> 499     err, enddata = Pipeline.run_pipeline(pipeline, source)
    500     context.teardown_errors(err, options, result)
    501     return result

~/code/lsup/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Pipeline.py in run_pipeline(pipeline, source, printtree)
    352                             exec("def %s(phase, data): return phase(data)" % phase_name, exec_ns)
    353                             run = _pipeline_entry_points[phase_name] = exec_ns[phase_name]
--> 354                     data = run(phase, data)
    355                     if DebugFlags.debug_verbose_pipeline:
    356                         print("    %.3f seconds" % (time() - t))

~/code/lsup/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Pipeline.py in run(phase, data)
    332
    333     def run(phase, data):
--> 334         return phase(data)
    335
    336     error = None

~/code/lsup/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Pipeline.py in generate_pyx_code_stage(module_node)
     50 def generate_pyx_code_stage_factory(options, result):
     51     def generate_pyx_code_stage(module_node):
---> 52         module_node.process_implementation(options, result)
     53         result.compilation_source = module_node.compilation_source
     54         return result

~/code/lsup/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/ModuleNode.py in process_implementation(self, options, result)
    140         self.find_referenced_modules(env, self.referenced_modules, {})
    141         self.sort_cdef_classes(env)
--> 142         self.generate_c_code(env, options, result)
    143         self.generate_h_code(env, options, result)
    144         self.generate_api_code(env, options, result)

~/code/lsup/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/ModuleNode.py in generate_c_code(self, env, options, result)
    376         # generate normal variable and function definitions
    377         self.generate_variable_definitions(env, code)
--> 378         self.body.generate_function_definitions(env, code)
    379         code.mark_pos(None)
    380         self.generate_typeobj_definitions(env, code)

~/code/lsup/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Nodes.py in generate_function_definitions(self, env, code)
    436         #print "StatListNode.generate_function_definitions" ###
    437         for stat in self.stats:
--> 438             stat.generate_function_definitions(env, code)
    439
    440     def generate_execution_code(self, code):

~/code/lsup/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Nodes.py in generate_function_definitions(self, env, code)
   9242                 entry.cname = cname
   9243
-> 9244         self.node.generate_function_definitions(env, code)
   9245
   9246     def generate_execution_code(self, code):

~/code/lsup/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Nodes.py in generate_function_definitions(self, env, code)
   1974         # ----- Function body -----
   1975         # -------------------------
-> 1976         self.generate_function_body(env, code)
   1977
   1978         code.mark_pos(self.pos, trace=False)

~/code/lsup/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Nodes.py in generate_function_body(self, env, code)
   1736
   1737     def generate_function_body(self, env, code):
-> 1738         self.body.generate_execution_code(code)
   1739
   1740     def generate_function_definitions(self, env, code):

~/code/lsup/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Nodes.py in generate_execution_code(self, code)
    442         for stat in self.stats:
    443             code.mark_pos(stat.pos)
--> 444             stat.generate_execution_code(code)
    445
    446     def annotate(self, code):

~/code/lsup/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Nodes.py in generate_execution_code(self, code)
   6185         for i, if_clause in enumerate(self.if_clauses):
   6186             self._set_branch_hint(if_clause, if_clause.body)
-> 6187             if_clause.generate_execution_code(code, end_label, is_last=i == last)
   6188         if self.else_clause:
   6189             code.mark_pos(self.else_clause.pos)

~/code/lsup/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Nodes.py in generate_execution_code(self, code, end_label, is_last)
   6247         self.condition.generate_disposal_code(code)
   6248         self.condition.free_temps(code)
-> 6249         self.body.generate_execution_code(code)
   6250         code.mark_pos(self.pos, trace=False)
   6251         if not (is_last or self.body.is_terminator):

~/code/lsup/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Nodes.py in generate_execution_code(self, code)
    442         for stat in self.stats:
    443             code.mark_pos(stat.pos)
--> 444             stat.generate_execution_code(code)
    445
    446     def annotate(self, code):

~/code/lsup/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/UtilNodes.py in generate_execution_code(self, code)
    324     def generate_execution_code(self, code):
    325         self.setup_temp_expr(code)
--> 326         self.body.generate_execution_code(code)
    327         self.teardown_temp_expr(code)
    328

~/code/lsup/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Nodes.py in generate_execution_code(self, code)
   6605         self.item.generate_evaluation_code(code)
   6606         self.target.generate_assignment_code(self.item, code)
-> 6607         self.body.generate_execution_code(code)
   6608         code.mark_pos(self.pos)
   6609         code.put_label(code.continue_label)

~/code/lsup/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Nodes.py in generate_execution_code(self, code)
    442         for stat in self.stats:
    443             code.mark_pos(stat.pos)
--> 444             stat.generate_execution_code(code)
    445
    446     def annotate(self, code):

~/code/lsup/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Nodes.py in generate_execution_code(self, code)
   5100     def generate_execution_code(self, code):
   5101         code.mark_pos(self.pos)
-> 5102         self.generate_rhs_evaluation_code(code)
   5103         self.generate_assignment_code(code)
   5104

~/code/lsup/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Nodes.py in generate_rhs_evaluation_code(self, code)
   5387
   5388     def generate_rhs_evaluation_code(self, code):
-> 5389         self.rhs.generate_evaluation_code(code)
   5390
   5391     def generate_assignment_code(self, code, overloaded_assignment=False):

~/code/lsup/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/ExprNodes.py in generate_evaluation_code(self, code)
    718             self.allocate_temp_result(code)
    719
--> 720         self.generate_result_code(code)
    721         if self.is_temp and not (self.type.is_string or self.type.is_pyunicode_ptr):
    722             # If we are temp we do not need to wait until this node is disposed

~/code/lsup/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/ExprNodes.py in generate_result_code(self, code)
  13135
  13136         code.putln(self.type.from_py_call_code(
> 13137             self.arg.py_result(), self.result(), self.pos, code, from_py_function=from_py_function))
  13138         if self.type.is_pyobject:
  13139             code.put_gotref(self.py_result())

~/code/lsup/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/PyrexTypes.py in from_py_call_code(self, source_code, result_code, error_pos, code, from_py_function, error_condition)
    512             source_code, result_code, error_pos, code,
    513             from_py_function or self.from_py_function,
--> 514             error_condition or self.error_condition(result_code)
    515         )
    516

~/code/lsup/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/PyrexTypes.py in from_py_call_code(self, source_code, result_code, error_pos, code, from_py_function, error_condition)
   2481     def from_py_call_code(self, source_code, result_code, error_pos, code,
   2482                           from_py_function=None, error_condition=None):
-> 2483         assert not error_condition, '%s: %s' % (error_pos, error_condition)
   2484         call_code = "%s(%s, %s, %s)" % (
   2485             from_py_function or self.from_py_function,

AssertionError: (<StringSourceDescriptor:carray.from_py>, 87, 19): (!__pyx_t_11) && PyErr_Occurred()
```

This is especially problematic in my 1000+-line program, where I had to find out what was causing the problem. Removing all ctypedefs for char arrays that were being assigned removed the error, but I'd like to know what is causing it.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Note: This is not a NUL-terminated string, but a byte sequence that may have NULs anywhere. That's why I am using `memcpy` rather than string functions or regular `=` assignments.

Comment: The problem isn't with `print()`. I eliminated it and the problem persists. See my update in regard to the NUL byte.

Comment: You have a few extra `[KLEN]`s, which are already taken care of by the typedefs. However that doesn't fix the problem. It's an error at the compilation stage and you should report it at https://github.com/cython/cython/issues

Comment: Sorry, the `SingleKey k[KLEN]` was just bad copy & paste. I corrected it.

Comment: @DavidW Thanks, it felt like a Cython issue but I wanted confirmation.

Comment: See issue at https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/2517